# alter the url of a given search result in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, search, replace

I'm trying to alter the url of a given search result within wordpress.
I have the follow js at the moment but it doesn't seam to alter the url. Perhaps since the search results are loading after the js? I'm not too sure.

The url I'm trying to change is www.examplesite.com/?team=dave-smith

I want to change it to: www.examplesite.com/our-team#dave-smith

Thanks

HTML

```
<h5 class="entry-title">
    <a href="www.examplesite.com/?team=dave-smith" title="Dave Smith">Dave Smith</a>
</h5>
```

I have the folllowing JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var mystring = $('.entry-title').find('a');
    mystring.replace(/?team=/g , "our-team");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `mystring` is a jQuery object wrapped around the `a` element.

If you want to just modify the `href` attribute, use `attr('href')`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var mystring = $('.entry-title').find('a')
      .attr('href', function (i,str) {
        return str.replace("?team=", "our-team"); // no need for regex here
      });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/43phL60a/

Comment: Perfect, works a treat. Nice with the function there, learning everyday! Thanks. @Blazemonger